# How can I get my Joomla 3 to work correctly?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I need to do a very simple task for school in Joomla 3.10.3 but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
I'm trying to create modules but I can't, it gives me those errors:

Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$checked_out in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla3\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\view.html.php on line 62

Warning: Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$position in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla3\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\tmpl\edit_positions.php on line 17

Warning: Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$position in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla3\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\tmpl\edit_positions.php on line 27

I've tried going into the files, but it looks like gibberish and I don't think I can fix it from there.
Maybe it's something with Joomla 3 being older and me having PHP version 8.1.10, dunno.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is almost certainly the template that you are using is not compatible with PHP 8.1. A lot of the older Joomla 3 templates will throw errors. If you can switch to PHP 7.4.x I expect the problems will stop

Comment: I reinstalled XAMPP to a older version that had PHP version 7. Everything seems working now, thanks for the help!